# memcached version 2.0 installation on centos working with php 5.3

Tags: php, memcached

i am upgrading one of our servers with Memcached (not memcache..). the installation was done with :
     `yum install memcached`

```
yum install php-pecl-memcache
```

all the memcached commands works, excpet a very important one - getAllKeys

the documentaion state that only version >= 2.0.0 of memcached can activate this command.

i am searching on how to install memcached 2.0 on centos and i cant find any repo links for this. could anyone help me with this ?